# how to lock web mobile application after one year for examole?

Tags: android, web-applications

I have web application for mobile and I need to lock the app after one year from using it for each customer, how I do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by :

1. set date variable in code.
2. compare it with the date in a customer device if less than one year
3. lock app

BR,